# How do I use Bonsai.io for Elastic Search for Magento?

Tags: search

I'm trying to setup Magento to leverage bonsai.io elasticsearch. I've installed the following module: https://github.com/jreinke/magento-elasticsearch and entered the configuration in the control panel, but it isn't able to proceed.

I got this working locally with a test install of ElasticSearch on the same machine as the Magento install. Not sure if this is a limitation with the extension or with my config. Note that for the server value, I'm putting the whole authenticated url. ex: https://user:pw@elasticsearchcluser.bonsai.io

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonsai creator/cofounder here.

I see a couple potential issues here. That particular module says it's for Elasticsearch 0.20, which is pretty old; the paid version it links to is also several versions behind. As of this writing, Bonsai is on the 1.4 series of Elasticsearch.

Next, the client it uses looks to be an old version of [Elastica](http://elastica.io), a PHP client for Elasticsearch. The configuration screenshot shown asks for a list of server IP and port combination. Furthermore there's no way to specify the protocol — presumably it's using HTTP on port 9200, however Bonsai defaults to HTTPS on the standard 443, though we also support HTTP on 80.

In short, there are a number of design assumptions in that particular module that may complicate getting it to work out of the box. Configuration may be possible, but if there are too many assumptions based on the ES 0.20 API, then that may be even harder to work around.

You may be able to get this to work by specifying the cluster hostname (e.g., `clustername-12345.region.bonsai.io`) for the server list. But then you'd also need a way to specify the cluster Basic Authentication, which is going to require some modifications to the module.

Beyond that, you'd need to work through the code and troubleshoot any individual problems that come up.

Unfortunately there's no clear and quick answer to this question. The module itself would need to be updated to work with Elasticsearch 1.x, and be modified to accept a standard URL for its cluster settings (or different/additional fields). If that was the case (or a different module found) it should work with Bonsai no problem.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm going to work on this and will post any results I get here.